# How to get numeric value from array in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an array like this

```
var records:Object = {};
var arr:Array = [
                records["nh"] = { medinc:66303},
                records["ct"] = { medinc:65958},
                records["nj"] = { medinc:65173},
                records["md"] = { medinc:64596},
                records["kk"] = { medinc:61321} 
            ];

arr.sortOn("medinc", Array.NUMERIC);
```

and I have the array sorted numerically. My question is how I can get the numeric value from each record? I want to use that value to set the width of different movie clips.

Something like

```
object1.width=(record for the [0] position in the array)
object2.width=(record for the [1] position in the array)
object3.width=(record for the [2] position in the array)
```

etc...

I hope this is clear enough. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trace(arr[0]['medinc']); // 61321
```

Basically, to address a certain field in the nested object, you address it as an associative array with an index of type String.